# Css is really ignoring me

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this program i am doing, and this includes css.

The thing I want help with you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/yupsdk/6MxfQ/10/

```
body { margin: auto; }

#fields {
    position: relative; 
    width: 408px; 
    height: 370px; 
    background: url('http://hhsrv.n.dk/chat/gfx/rum/sms/old/gummicelle.jpg') repeat-x; border: 1px #DDD solid; 
}

.field {
    width: 2px;  
    height: 2px; 
    background: #FF0000; 
    position: absolute;
}

#user { 
    top: 500;   
    border: 1px solid black; 
    background: url('http://www.geekabit.dk/community/profil/figur/1335803573_149116.gif') no-repeat;  
    width: 52px; 
    height: 77px; 
}
```

When the script is loaded, the man need to stand on the number, like when it spawns it need to stand on 25, not under it like i does rigth now. If you have console in your browser, it will tell you what field it is soposed to stand on.

Can't really figure it out. I have tried z-index and top, but it didn't work. I hope you can help me out here.

Comment: You know that whitespace (including line breaks) is allowed in CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want `position:relative` and `z-index`.

Number under shirt: http://jsfiddle.net/6MxfQ/17/

Number over shirt: http://jsfiddle.net/6MxfQ/16/

```
#user { border: 1px solid black;
   background: url('http://www.geekabit.dk/community/profil/figur/1335803573_149116.gif')
   no-repeat; width: 52px; height: 77px;
   position:relative;z-index:1;}
```

Comment: It is still standing under the 25 field?

Comment: You mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/6MxfQ/14/ ? I just offset him with margins.

Comment: Mike think you misunderstood me, the number have to be under his shirt, so the gif is on top of the number

Comment: And if you want the number on his shirt, then just remove that position:relative;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are simply appending the #user div, so it comes after the number that has been selected. In order to make it appear like the user is standing above the number, you need to use negative margins:

```
#user { ... margin: -97px 0 0 -20px; }
```

If you want to adjust the position of the user, play with those top and left margin values.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/5RbZB/)